# What means "any[]" in js/ts array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I learning Angular2 now. In lesson i read that i must save datas into "any" array and after this into example was code like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GithubService } from '../../services/github.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'profile',
  template: `<h1>Profile Component</h1>`,
})
export class ProfileComponent  {
  user:any[];

  constructor(private _githubService:GithubService){
    // this._githubService.getUser().subscribe(user => {console.log(user)});
    this._githubService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
       this.user = user;
    });
  }
}
```

What means `user:any[];`? I tried to search it in google on github and so on, but found nothing. Don't know event what to read.

Comment: It means an array of `any` type elements

Comment: That means if i need i can save string and object in one array?

Comment: @NikitaM Yes, you can store anything at all as an element of the array. `any[]` merely say it's an array with *unknown* elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to know is that `any[]` is only a valid variable declaration in Typescript not in Javascript.

It is a two part declaration - `[]` is used in Typescript to declare an array of values.  The `any` is used to declare that the entries in the array can be of any type.  In contrast, you could specify only one valid type for the array.  For example, `string[]` would declare an array of `string` objects.  The Typescript compiler would then check that you only add `string` objects to the array.

Answer (score 2):

`user: any;` means we can store a variables of type string, number, object, boolean, etc.

`user: any[];` means `user` must be an array and the array elements can have type strings, number,s objects, booleans etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `any` usually indicated lack of a proper type. Therefore I strongly recomend to define an interface `User` that describes the user object.

Or even, in this case, use some prepared typed API - like https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-github-api